# jquery auto generated on click event not working for me

Tags: jquery

I append the tr of table following manner

```
 $('#selectStudents').append("<tr><td>"+rollno+"</td>\n\
    <td>"+name+"</td>\n\
    <td><a href='#' class='att-time-btn toggle' onclick='periodPopup("+rollno+")' id='periodBox'></a></td>\n\
    <td><input type='checkbox' name='' id='mrng1' checked></td>\n\
    <td><input type='checkbox' name='' id='evng' checked></td></tr>"
 );
```

but this code is not working for me when call the periodPopup() function

Comment: what is the value of `rollno`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is in `rollno`, if it is a string value then it could fail

```
onclick='periodPopup(\""+rollno+"\")'
```

Answer (score 1):

onclick is deprecated. Take a look at what I've done here:

https://jsfiddle.net/gdczgros/

```
$( function() {
    var rollno = 101;

    $('#selectStudents').append("<tr><td>"+rollno+"</td>\n\
        <td>"+name+"</td>\n\
        <td><a href='#' class='att-time-btn toggle' data-rollno='"+rollno+"' id='periodBox'>Test</a></td>\n\
        <td><input type='checkbox' name='' id='mrng1' checked></td>\n\
        <td><input type='checkbox' name='' id='evng' checked></td></tr>"
     );

    // VVVVVVV
    $("#selectStudents").on('click', ".att-time-btn", function(event) {
        periodPopup( $(this).attr("data-rollno") );
    } );
    // ^^^^^^^

    function periodPopup( rollno ) {
        console.log( rollno );
    }
} );
```